# Enable Disable Dropdowns and submit buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i am trying to develop a web app which requires the validation in such a way that when the page loads i would have a single drop down select box enabled and rest of the things such as textbox,buttons all should be in disable mode. when i would select the item from the first select box,then only the other text box should enabled.

after i am done with selecting all the fields, then only the submit button should be enabled.

please suggest me the way in javascript or provide any code snippets so that i can design efficiently.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Post your code, them we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok every select box has onchange attribute which fires a function and in that function you can write to enable your text boxes and any thing else you want

```
<select onchange = 'func();'></select>
```

after that text boxes has onkeypress attr which will fire function in that you can write to enable sumbit button

```
<input type='text' onkeypress="func();"/>
```

In this function you can check whether all text boxes are filled or not and than you can enable your submit button..

Answer (score 0):

You must try using jquery, sample code is as below and its tested too.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#xyz").change(function(){
            var fields = $("input");
            fields.removeAttr("disabled");          
        });

    });

</script>


<form action="">

    <select name="xyz" id="xyz">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" disabled="disabled"/>
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled"/>

</form>
```

Feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first map the select list values to fields that need to be enabled. You can use classes so that multiple fields can be enabled at once.

```
var choiceFieldMapping = {
    'val1': '.first',
    'val2': '.second',
    // and so on
};
```

We also need to know which values have been selected:

```
var selectedValues = {
    'val1': false,
    'val2': false,
    // and so on, all false by default
};
```

Next we disable all inputs and enable the select:

```
function resetDisable() {
    $('form :input').prop('disabled', true);
    $('form #firstSelect').prop('disabled', false);
}
resetDisable(); // Call it once to reset the form to initial state
```

When user changes the selected option, we do this:

```
$('form #firstSelect').change(function() {
    // Current value
    var v = $(this).val();

    // Enable the fields
    resetDisable();
    $(choiceFieldMapping[v]).prop('disabled', false);

    // Update the selectedValues object
    selectedvalues[v] = true;

    // Check if all values have been selected
    var allSelected = Object.keys(selectedValues).every(function(key) {
        return selectedValues[key];
    });

    if (allSelected) {
        // Enable submit button
        $('form #submit').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```